# WMI Query to detect the Microsoft office architecture installed in a Windows 7 machine

Tags: ms-office, sccm

I am working in SCCM,while installing SAP Bussiness object Analysis ,MS Office is one of the  prerequest.I need to add a condition in Task sequence to check the version of MS office architecture before installing SAP.

I got registery path to check that "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook"
BITNESS =x64 or x86. if the machine don't have outlook this wont work.

So i need a WMI query to check the bitness or a any other registry path to check the bitness of office . please help

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not a place to dump your to-do/requirements lists. What have YOU done to try and accomplish this so far? We are not here to write code for you or do your job for you.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with a WMI query, just create a task sequence for deploying SAP and use conditions to determine if Office is installed or not. It'll be much easier in the short term.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this outside of the task sequence. How I will do is:

Method 1:
 - Create device collection based on the condition (I would prefer using hardware inventory data to filter)
 - deploy the SAP Application/package to the 'correct' collection

Method 2:
For application type of deployment, there are 'Requirement' settings on the deployment type. What you need to do is to create a registry based Global Condition (almost clicks-and-types-and-clicks) and attach this to the SAP application deployment type.

If you are not familiar with Global Condition, below is an official document link URL which will get you started:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg682048.aspx